# Projecting Numbers In Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, vba

i am looking to predict my next sales per day based on 10 years of data. So in Column A i have the date and in column B i have my total sales for that day. is there anyway i can predict the amount of sales i will have tomorrow.

an excerpt

1. Month       Sales
2. 1-Aug       3010
3. 2-Aug       4500
4. 3-Aug       4400
5. 4-Aug       5400
6. 5-Aug       7295
7. 6-Aug     8195
8. 7-Aug        x

issue is its not linear.

any advice would be amazing.

Comment: To predict it you would need to fit some sort or model.  Is it cyclic?, exponential, is it close to the average from the last couple months, etc.  Without that you can't really predict anything.  A graph of the output might help to get a general shape of the data.

Comment: This is probably much more a statistic / mathematics question than a programming question. I might be wrong, but there is no pre-made function that does this. And programming this would just be implementing a mathematics formula.

Comment: i dont think there is a formula that does it. I was hoping i was wrong and just dont know enough excel to be right. However ive seen formulas be made into functions through vba, issue is idk the formula to use to make it. I was hoping for some help with that idea. As for the data - this is all i have. I have 10 years of data and no idea how to predict the next day or if its possible. Thank you for your comments. Any idea if its a possibility to get the FV of a non linear graph?

Answer (score 1):

LINEST requires numbers rather than dates for input, so please try:

```
=SUM(LINEST(B2:B7,A2:A7)*{41858,1})
```

Comment: Though he specifically said that the issued wasn't linear. And `LINEST()` does a "linear estimation".

Comment: i tried your idea but its is all linear. no matter how far down i go or try to use your idea to calculate what aug 5th would be. this is 2014.